# weird php behaviour with classes and static methods

Tags: php

I maintain an application that uses a (to me) surprising PHP quirk/bug/feature. Consider this code:

```
<?php
class Bar {
    // called statically
    public function doStuff() {
        print_r($this);
    }
}

class Foo {
    public function main() {
        Bar::doStuff();
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->main();
```

Running on PHP 5.2.x, the output is:

```
Foo Object ( )
```

That means, although `Bar::doStuff()` is called statically, it still has access to `$this` where `$this` is a reference to the object that called `Bar::doStuff()`. Never came across that behaviour until recently. Quite evil to rely on this in production code if you ask me.

If you add a `static` and change the method signature to `public static function doStuff()` it throws a `E_NOTICE:  Undefined variable: this` - which seems right to me.

Anyone has an explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP 5.3 at least, you get a strict warning:

`PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method Bar::doStuff() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /tmp/test.php on line 11`

And quite rightfully so.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, then I know which application I wont upgrade to PHP 5.3 any time soon...

Comment: @Max This has nothing to do with the PHP Version. Use `error_reporting(-1)` to enable all errors, including `E_STRICT`. Will raise on PHP < 5.3 too

Comment: There are some (old) bugs reported on this: #12622 or #20089 for example. I especially like hellys comment 2004 in #20089 ... although couldn't find any change notes that "fixes" this behavior between 5.2.x and 5.3 ..

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to create some type of Printable_Object class and simply inherit from that. Add the doStuff() method to that class, and use the inherited method properly.